# Proving a trigonometric identity by infinite series

Tags: trigonometry, summation

We know that:
$$\cos(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}.$$
And 
$$\sin(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.$$
Using this prove that $$\cos(x) \cdot \sin(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k(2x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} =\dfrac{\sin(2x)}{2}.$$

Comment: How far have you gotten?

Comment: I haven't made any progress with sums. I tried grouping terms with equal powers of $x$. But I don't have ideas of how to solve it with sums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously $\sin(x)\cdot\cos(x)$ is an entire odd function, hence
$$[x^{2k}]\sin(x)\cos(x)=0,$$
while:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}[x^{2k+1}]\sin(x)\cos(x) &=& \sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-j}}{(2(k-j))!}\cdot\frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!}\\&=&\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{2k+1}{2j}\\&=&\frac{(-4)^k}{(2k+1)!}\end{eqnarray*}$$
is exactly $[x^{2k+1}]\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}$. This is more or less the same as writing $$\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2},\qquad \cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
and multiplying the two expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint:  If $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$$ and $$g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^k,$$ then $$f(x) g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k,$$ where $$c_k = \sum_{j=0}^k a_j b_{k-j}.$$  This is known as the *Cauchy product* or convolution of ordinary generating functions.